# Quickly retrieving multiple page titles in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I currently have a program that uses the net\http library to retrieve page sources until it finds a title that matches with a string given by the user. The code works, however it is really slow when it comes to cycling through multiple pages to find a title. Is there a way that I could only retrieve the title rather than the entire page of code?

This is what the code looks like:

```
require 'net\http'
class Card
    attr_accessor :name
    #attr_reader :s, :go, :here

    def getEm
        @i = 1
        @card = Net::HTTP.get(URI("http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=#{@i}"))    
        while true
            @card =~ /(#{self.name})/i ? break : @i = @i + 1
            @card = Net::HTTP.get(URI("http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=#{@i}"))
        end
        puts @i
        puts @card.match(/(#{self.name})/i)
    end
end
$cardname = "Basalt Monolith"
c = Card.new
c.name = ARGV[0] || $cardname
c.getEm
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: No,  you have to retrieve the page. You could parallelize the fetches, though, e.g., https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus